# Format Margin / Padding in DataGrid ColumnHeader

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to place a canvas in the columnheader of a datagrid, which is aligned to the far left of the colum, i.e. no margin between the column and the control. However, there is always some space between the column and the control. I'm wondering how I get rid of the small space shown yellow in the picture? I also wonder, why none of the background colors (ItemsControl = LightBlue, Canvas = LemonChiffon) are visible, but I guess that is the same reason.

[image]

The desired design looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vmJp}">
    <DataGrid  x:Name="dgProj" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"  CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Baustellen}" BorderThickness="0" HeadersVisibility="Column" Padding="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
         ....

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="1*" x:Name="coPlanung">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Monate, ElementName=dgProj}" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource d2x}">
                                                <Binding Path="Date" Mode="OneWay" />
                                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="coPlanung" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <Canvas Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=coPlanung}" Margin="0" Background="LemonChiffon"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <!--Monthnames-->
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat={}{0:MMM-yyyy}, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Margin="0">
                                        <TextBox.Width>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource d2b}">
                                                <Binding Path="Date" Mode="OneWay" />
                                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="coPlanung" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBox.Width>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

Setting the margin to -5 doesn't show the desired design:

[image]

Code

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="coPlanung">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-5"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering how I get rid of the small space shown yellow in the picture?

You could set the `HeaderStyle` of the `DataGridTemplateColumn` to a `DataGridColumnHeader` style with negative margins:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="coPlanung">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-5"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    ...
```

> I also wonder, why none of the background colors (ItemsControl = LightBlue, Canvas = LemonChiffon) are visible, but I guess that is the same reason.

Try to specify a `Height` for the `Canvas`. The ItemsControl's background is "hidden" behind the `ItemsPanel`.

**Edit:** As you have already noticed you could also try set the `Margin` of the `ContentPresenter`:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">                                        
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-5"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: I updated the question, since it did not work, but you pointed me in the right direction - Thank you very much. If you update your answer, I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: I updated the answer. Which version of Windows are you on?

Comment: I'm using windows 10. Since all clients run also on win 10, I didn't focus on that. Should this be considered somehow?

Comment: Probably not. Just wonder why setting the Margin of the cell itself worked for me. But I didn' tried with the exact same markup as you which probably explains this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `RowHeaderWidth="0"`, it's a `DataGrid` property.

//edit
Maybe something else is interfering. 
Here is a link of the most important properties to style your `DataGrid`: [Styling Microsoft’s WPF datagrid](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2009/01/20/styling-microsofts-wpf-datagrid/)

And here is a short example

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}" />
```

[image: without]

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}"
          RowHeaderWidth="0"/>
```

[image: with]

As you can see the `RowHeader` is gone.

Comment: I think my picture doesn't Show the problem too well. The question is not how to get rid of the rowheader, rather than, how to format the columnheader, so there is now space left of the control in it. In your example, there should be no space between the light grey line and Zwei.

Comment: Haha, ok. I thought you just want to get rid if the yellow area and that looked like a RowHeader for me ;)

Comment: Maybe you can post an image which shows the desired design.